# Get VMware remote console access from website

Tags: web-applications, vmware

I know that there are browser plugins, that allows to connect to VMware virtual machine remote console.
But is it possible to make similar console on website? (using for example JavaScript or some framework) That on my website I will have some frame, which behaves like VMware remote console.
I have all VM information (IP of VMware host, login credentials, VM UUID and IP).

What steps I should take, to have solution like this?

Comment: Do you want to implement a similar VMware Console browser plugin using only HTML+JS? Using HTML5? Have I understood you correctly? Why don’t you want using original VMware Console browser plugin on your page?

Comment: According to http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.webaccess.doc_41/managing_virtual_machines/t_install_the_vmware_remote_console_plug-in_in_mozilla_firefox.html client have to go to administrative panel in vSphere web access to install this plugin. I do not want user to get into vSphere web access. Is there a way to install it and use without this access? Is it possible to provide this plugin access in my custom web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store distributives of these plugins in your web application and allow users to download them. I think it should not conflict with the license, because the user accepts the license of plugin at the time of installation.
You can load plugins from vCenter. In vCenter Server Appliance 5.1 plugins locate on the path:

`/usr/lib/vmware-vsphere-client/server/work/org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer_3.0.3.RELEASE/staging/global/bundle/com.vmware.vsphere.client.containerapp/5.1.0/container-app-war-5.1.0.war/vmrc`

The vCenter contains three files of VMware Console browser plugin (for Windows and Linux):

- VMware-ClientIntegrationPlugin-5.1.0.exe
- VMware-ClientIntegrationPlugin-5.1.0.i386.bundle
- VMware-ClientIntegrationPlugin-5.1.0.x86_64.bundle

Embedding plugin to a page of web site has few niceties (getting credentials of user, display popup window and menu items over plugin, etc.). If you have any problems, write about them, probably I can help you (I recently implemented it).

Comment: I've followed the infor here: http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/02/how-to-access-vcloud-director-remote.html  but now I get "Error connecting to main vCloud Director UI. Please close this window, verify that your session is still active, and try again." error when I paste the generated url to the web browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

VMWware released [VMware Remote Console SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vmrc/) which allows you to implement that